# Can I ask for salary increase now that I've graduated?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I did my final college internship at the company where I still work now. The internship was about five months long. At the end of my internship I kept working for the same compagny over the summer.

Now summer is ending and school is coming back. I will be missing a few courses before entering university so I asked them if they would have a job for me over the next year. They said yes. They know it will be somewhere around 25-30 hour per week depending on my schedule.

The salary they gave me during my internship is about 2/3 of the salary that people graduated in computer technology are actually making. For the summer I didn't ask them for more because I didn't want to be this guy "always asking for more".

Now I have graduated.

What would be the best way to ask them to raise my salary without looking like "I just graduated and you should pay me X more an hour"?

Edit: The classes I still need to take are in order to get to the university, those weren't simply included in my program.

Comment: To clarify, are you being paid 2/3 of the salary of current entry-level full-time people, for working part time (63-75%  of the full-time hours)?

Comment: So you graduated from college but not university then?  I don't understand how "to get to the university" fits with this question.

Comment: @JBKing I leave in québec, canada. Here we have little school, high school, college than university.

Comment: @jcmeloni for example I make about 12$ per hour an people got around 18$ per hour

Comment: I'm in Alberta, Canada.  I grew up in Ontario, Canada and in both places one can go from high school to university, thus I had to ask.

Comment: @JBKing Québec got a different school system. We can do it here also, but I require 25 years (for most university). The normal way is college than university here

Comment: While you might like the work and the workplace, the going rate for good programmers in Canada (or at least Toronto) is the 50K-60K range from what I can tell on Craigslist, so none of you are getting paid market rates. Figure out what you should be making and then find a job that pays it.  As a side note, governments never pay market rates.  Therefore, a skill the government pays 30K for might get anywhere from 48K to 60K from a private employer. In the US the 'public sector' is about 40% of the economy, Canada's is likely to be similar.

Comment: @im_a_noob So you just graduated CJEP?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes I finished in may.

Comment: @MeredithPoor My region is under market rate as I said before. Toronto and Montreal are big city with higher demand for programmer.

Comment: @im_a_noob - I can see your complaint at $12 per hour, however your current employer may have the attitude that as long as you're willing to work at that rate they'll continue to keep you around.  The only way to get their attention is to put in your notice.  This means you need an alternative employer - in or out of town.  Do you ever root around on ca.indeed.com? This might tell you something.  Toronto has about 100 listings per day for developers, this is more than San Francisco, Boston, DC, or NYC taken individually.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere We will see at this time. Probably going to leave. They are aware of this. Any way I have talked to them for the next year.

Comment: You should start applying for other jobs to find out what you're worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *always* ask for more. You would go to them and basically say, "Now that I have a degree, I think I'm worth more." and see what happens.

But you aren't yet a full-timer. And from a hiring manager's point of view, they may not be sure if you will be sticking around for the long haul, or are just staying there until you complete your education. (After your latest comments, you indicate don't believe you will be sticking around and that they know it. I'd be surprised if they give you the same pay as someone who they think will be around.)

I know I like to give benefits to folks who I expect to be around longer, at the expense of those who may be gone in a year or two.

But, it seldom hurts to ask! All they can say is "No".

Comment: Yeah you're right. Of course they are more will to pay more people directly related to the business (I only developping a side sowfware for a departement) and that plan to stay there for long time. Anyway I think the only way to know is to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, "I just graduated and you should pay me X more an hour" is a fine thing to say, **if in fact you had graduated**. But you haven't, you have some more classes to finish.

You could try negotiating now what your raise will be when you graduate. That will probably work out fine. But don't expect them to pay it to you until you are actually finished your school work.

Comment: Actually I graduated. The class I need to take weren't in my program and in order to get to the university I need them

Comment: for most companies, part of graduating is being free to join a company full time and start to build a future with them. If you're still taking classes, and looking forward to university, you're kind of taking yourself out of that category. It can't hurt to ask, but you might not get what you want.

Comment: Well I know that. Of course I would like $20+ per hour but I think it would be asking for too mutch. But how ever I still worth more than 12.50 per hour. I mean you can that kinda easy without any diploma or anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a case for the value you bring to them, and how your graduating (if you really have done so, it's not clear) provides a benefit to them and is worth $X more.  It sounds like you've already researched what similar companies in your area are paying for people with similar skills for a similar job.

It can be awkward asking for more money, and for ideas on that, I recommend reading [AskAManager](http://www.askamanager.org) about ways to handle the actual negotiations.  But you do need to have a solid case for the value you provide to them, and why paying $X more is reasonable.  If they agree, fine.  If they don't agree, then you have to decide how long you work for them to continue get experience, and then prove you are worth more by actually getting that better paying job.

Answer (score -1):

I am near 40 and I have switched jobs alot over the years. I have never asked my current employer for a raise. When I interview for my next job, I tell them I want a raise. Asking for a raise rarely works. At a company large enough to have an HR department, your boss has little say over your salary. These days wages are pretty stagnant. However, I have found that I can still raise my salary by switching jobs. Works very well. When you are in a 'want a raise' job search instead of 'I need a job' search you can tell them up front you are looking for an increase so you don't waste your time just to find out later they don't want to pay what your looking for.

asking for a raise is too risky. Generally you won't get it. You also put yourself out there. Some places may fire you if they are concerned you will leave. They will probably call it a 'downsizing' or something else. Its just not worth it. You never really know. Safer to get the money somewhere else. Switching jobs is not a big deal.

Comment: I think my situation is a bit more different than yours. Also, following your logic, you don't have anything to risk to ask them "I want a raise or I'll be searching for something else". At worse the will fire you at best you get the raise.